# Calling lotusscript function from a java agent

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In a notes database, we have a script library with lotusscript functions that make connection with other ERP systems. Those functions are written in Lotusscript. Is it possible from a java agent to execute a lotusscript function that is in the scriptlibrary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. But you can write a web service or a Lotusscript agent (accessible through a REST call) that encapsulate the functionality of the script library.